# Where to Initialize NSMutableArray to Prevent Erasure

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to create a NSMutableArray that has a float (converted to NSInteger) added to it when a button is pressed. The button is connected to a timerViewController and its block of code in the implementation file is as follows (you can disregard the if statement for the matter of this question):

```
- (IBAction)timeSaveButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([self.timerStartOrStop.titleLabel.text  isEqual: @"Start"]){
        RecordedTimes *myTimes = [[RecordedTimes alloc] init];
        [myTimes addANewTime: self.timerTime];
    }
}
```

The "RecordedTimes" class it refers to has the NSMutableArray and "addANewTime" method declared in the .h file

```
@interface RecordedTimes : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *recordedTimes;

-(void)addANewTime: (float) timerTime;

@end
```

Its implementation file is

```
@implementation RecordedTimes

-(void) addANewTime:(float)timerTime{
    NSMutableArray *myTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [myTimes addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timerTime]];
}

@end
```

The problem is that each time I save a new time, the array empties and stores only the most recent timerTime. I understand that this is because my viewController (and the addANewTime method) initializes the array each time, causing it to erase its contents. How to fix that problem and where to initialize the array instead is where I'm confused.

Please be detailed in your response. I am a newbie to XCode and Objective-C. Thanks.

Comment: It's about scope of instance variable. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class

Comment: Try to initialize NSMutableArray in viewDidLoad to avoid it being reinitialized everytime when you pass a message to addANewTime.

Comment: If you find any answer compliant to your question please do vote it right.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared the `NSMutableArray` property called `recordedTimes` but never initialized it to an empty array. In somewhere convenient, like the `init` method, you can initialize it:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.recordedTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then change `addANewTime:` to this:

```
- (void)addANewTime:(float)timerTime{
    [self.recordedTimes addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timerTime]];
}
```

This makes sure your mutable array property is initialized once (since `init` is called once when you initialize your object), and then you append to the end of the array each time `addANewTime:` is called.

---

Additionally, you're re-creating the `RecordedTimes` object every time the `timeSaveButton:` method is called. You'll want to follow the same pattern, and store it as a property on your view controller's class and then set it once in somewhere like the `viewDidLoad` method.

---

Aside: You've probably noticed that you can't store an `int` (or, generally, a *primitive*, non–object type) in an `NSMutableArray` object. You might consider converting the `timerTime` to an `NSNumber` with `[NSNumber numberWithInt:timerTime]` and storing that in the array instead of a string.

Comment: Which file would the init method go in? And also, doesn't it require you to return something at the end since its return type is id?

Comment: You'd put the init method in your RecordedTimes class. And yeah, nice catch! I've edited the example to return self.

Comment: Hm, I haven't read anything about the init method so far. So does it basically just run whenever an object of a certain class is initialized?

Comment: One more clarification. When you said "follow the same pattern, and store it as a property on your view controller's class", I assume you mean to declare the RecordedTimes class as a property. Would it be done like this: @property (nonatomic) RecordedTimes *myTimes;

Comment: Yep! And remember to initialize it only once somewhere like viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

To initializing a property, I usually do it in either:

In the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller.

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.recordedTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Or lazy initialize it when you need it, in this case, when you add your first time to it:

```
-(void) addANewTime:(float)timerTime {
    if (!self.recordedTimes) {
       self.recordedTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.recordedTimes addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timerTime]];
}
```

Also, you're doing several thing wrong:

- First, you have a local variable, which gets deallocated after the method `addANewTime` is executed. Instead, you should declare a `@property`, to keep your array alive as long as the viewController (or the objects which has the property) is alive.
- I assume you wanted to do that with `@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *recordedTimes;`, but you should actually use that, instead of a local variable.

Comment: `assign` and `strong` are not related. A property can have both `assign` and `strong` semantics. Additionally, all object properties are `strong` by default under ARC.

Comment: I did not know that! Edited the answer. PS: Damn, I've written `strong` like a million times for no reason then...

Comment: Yup! When I found out I had a lot of fun going through all my code and deleting strong :)

Comment: I can't use self.recordedTimes in my viewController because it recordedTimes was only declared in the RecordedTimes object.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ()
{
    RecordedTimes *myTimes = [[RecordedTimes alloc] init];
}
```

The `myTimes` instance is only valid in `if {}` statement.

```
-(void) addANewTime:(float)timerTime
{
    NSMutableArray *myTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Also, `myTimes` instance is valid only in `addNewTime:` method.

That's why it seems to initialized every time.